# Simplenews: node links not working

Tags: views, 7, emails

The problem I face is the following:
I have set up [simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) for creating newsletters. I am able to select articles, pages, events etc. which are already displayed on the website itself.
However, after I selected the ones I want to show up in the newsletter and create a table of contents, there is no link to the article. It just shows the plain text without linking. Also the view mode dropdown menue is empty.

can anybody help me with this?
cheers,
nebelwueste

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your Views settings but you may need to change the Field settings to link back to the full article.

E.g. See the bottom checkbox.

[image: link_to_content]